# Different matplotlib images - show vs pdf

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, vector, histogram

I am using matplotlib to generate some histograms. When I am comparing the image generated by show

[plt.show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTaqb.png)

with the pdf generated by either savefig or saving from show window I see this ugliness:

[exported vector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPajj.png)

It looks like matplotlib reduced amount of detail in edges of simple bars.

Comment: Those are two different plots. You should produce a [mcve] and compare the outputs of this minimal example. Also define 'ugliness' - what do you not like about the plot and what would you have the plot look like instead?

Comment: Agreed, these are different plots.  savefig saves the "current figure".  So, if you create one figure, view it with pl.show() then make another figure, but do NOT view it, savefig will save this last figure even though you are not showing it.  Just something to check...

Comment: I am sorry, I did not point out that the plots are the same - I just zoomed on the same region of the plot. My point is - in pl.show() you can see nice edges around each bar, in saved pdf of the eaxactly same figure in pl.show() there are no edges, just overlayed bars